# Why isn't my nb-search appearing in my page?

Tags: html, angular, nebular

I created a homepage that has a navbar which I intended on putting nebular search in since I really liked it's design but for some reason after following their [instructions](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/global-search/overview#nbsearchcomponent) I still couldn't get it to appear.

```
<nb-layout>
<nb-layout-header fixed>
    <nb-search type="rotate-layout></nb-search>
</nb-layout-header>
</nb-layout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can help you if you improve your question. Which search navbar are you referring to on the website link you have posted? There is example code (TS and HTML) on the website. Please include a direct link or better yet copy the example you would like to use here along with what you have tried. A full minimal example is required. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In the link I provided earlier, there's a basic setup which contains how you could use the nb-search component but when I've tried adding it to my project It didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most likely cause of your issue**

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1275

You need to add `"./node_modules/nebular-icons/scss/nebular-icons.scss"`
to `angular.json`

This makes the search icon appear.

**In depth**

I managed to get this working by following the getting started tutorial https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/install-based-on-starter-kit#production-bundle

I decided to use the html from their website:

```
  <nb-layout>
    <nb-layout-header fixed>
      <nb-search type="rotate-layout"></nb-search>

    </nb-layout-header>

    <nb-sidebar>
    </nb-sidebar>

    <nb-layout-column>
      <nb-card accent="info">
        <nb-card-header>You searched for:</nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-body>
          <h3>{{ value || '-' }}</h3>
        </nb-card-body>
      </nb-card>
    </nb-layout-column>
  </nb-layout>
```

The tricky thing with this is making sure to import all the correct modules:
`NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),` was put in when I installed `@nebula/themes`

```
import {
  NbThemeModule,
  NbLayoutModule,
  NbCardModule,
  NbSidebarModule,
  NbSidebarService,
  NbSearchModule,
} from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbCardModule,
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbSearchModule
  ],
  providers: [NbSidebarService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Again re-using the example code on the website:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  value = '';

  constructor(private searchService: NbSearchService) {

    this.searchService.onSearchSubmit()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.value = data.term;
      })

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```